# How to pass JavaScript variables to PHP without reload the page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

i want to assign javascript variable value to php variable to loop products

**here is my php code:**

```
$products = wc_get_products( array( 
  'include' => $products_ids // `**i want to pass value from javascript here**`
) );

  foreach ( $products as $product ) {
     // fetching my product details
  }
```

**here is my js code:**

```
  (function($){

    $(document).ready(function(){

      $(document).on('change', '#myform', function(e) {

        
        e.preventDefault();

        data = $(this).serialize();

        var settings = {
            "url": "<?php  echo WC_AJAX::get_endpoint( 'myajaxfunction' ) ?>",
            "method": "POST",
            "data": data,
          }
          $.ajax(settings).done(function (result) {
            // i want to make $products_ids = result
            // result value is array(1,2);
          });
      });
    });
  })(jQuery);
```

**

1. i want to make $products_ids = result so i can pass it in my php
   code,
2. result value is array(1,2);

**

Comment: use [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: @LawrenceCherone could you please write for me as example? thanks.